# Создать карусельное меню

Tags: html, jquery, css

Друзья, возник срочный вопрос: никак не могу понять, как создать меню как в примере http://agelber.com/blog/looping-carousel, но так чтобы отображалось несколько элементов, а не один и только с использованием указаных технологий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Случилось так, что публикация вопроса не произошла, а решение я уже написал сам :) Оставлю его здесь - может кому-нибудь пригодится. Мне в данном случае не требовалась карусель, но её несложно добавить, исследуя оба примера.

```
$(function () {
        var currentIndex = 0, itemCount = $('.carousel > li').length;
        var shownItems = 3;

        $('.carousel > li').slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + shownItems).addClass('active');
        $('.carousel-nav').on('click', function () {
            var isNext = $(this).hasClass('next');
            $('.carousel > li').slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + shownItems).removeClass('active');
            currentIndex = (((currentIndex + (isNext ? 1 : -1)) >= 0) && ((currentIndex + (isNext ? 1 : -1)) <= itemCount - shownItems)) ? (currentIndex + (isNext ? 1 : -1)) : currentIndex;
            $('.carousel > li').slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + shownItems).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/viroff/4sj9pq0f/